# GSAP - Should I kill a tween before overriding it?

Tags: javascript, animation, tween, gsap

Let's say I'm tweening an object with GSAP.

```
var object = {opacity: 0};
var tween = TweenLite.to(object, 1, {opacity: 1});
```

And then, at *t = 0.5* :

```
var tweenBack = TweenLite.to(object, 1, {opacity: 0});
```

Do I need to `tween.kill()` before creating `tweenBack` or is it okay to create a tween on a tweening object?

It seems to work when I try, but just want to make sure this case is handled by GSAP.

Comment: afaik, no need to kill() before overriding it.

Comment: no need to kill()